# jQuery and ASP.NET Page load

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html, pageload

I test jQuery and ASP.NET with Webcontrols and in my test load the Side everytime new if I click on the Button. The jQuery Code add a Css Class to a Label.

My aspx:

```
      <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Main.aspx.cs" Inherits="jQueryAnwendung.Main" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>jQuery Anwendung</title>

    <script src="Scripte/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .CssKlasse 
        {
            background:red;
            font-size:40px; 
            }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#<%= b1.ClientID%>").click(function (event) {
                $("#<%= bild1.ClientID %>").slideToggle('slow');
            });

        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="b1" runat="server" text="Bild verkleinern/vergrößern"/>
        <asp:Image ID="bild1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Theme/net.png" Width="50" Height="50" /> 
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

What can I do?

tarasov

Comment: What do you want to get? If your button should not to fire post to server, don't use <asp:Button>. Use html button.

Comment: add return false after toggle statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside your handler, prevent the button from behaving normally:

```
$("#<%= b1.ClientID%>").click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault(); //prevent the control to act in its default way
  $("#<%= bild1.ClientID %>").slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The generated id is more verbose; open your browser and click *View source*. You will notice it. Copy and paste the ID into your jQuery selector.

Another way is to call `b1.clientID` inside your `.aspx`: `$("<%= b1.ClientID %>")`, which will output the generated `clientID` at runtime.

Since ASP.NET 4, `StaticMode` allows you to have complete control over the generated ID. For more information, check it out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx

Answer (score 1):

if you using asp controls you have 2 ways to handle it

First is change `"#b1` and `"#l1"` to `"<%= #b1.ClientID%>"` and `"<%= #l1.ClientID %>"` in your jQuery function

Second is to add attribute `ClientIDMode="Static"` to your `asp:Button` and `asp:Label`

Comment: which way doesn't work? edit you question and show how did you make this:)

Comment: ok I've see problem is you add both solution. Use 1-st or second not both same time;)

Answer (score 1):

Asp button causes Post back when you click it - page reloads and your script is not executed, you can use HTML button instead or try to disable postback on this button.